# Based on Selected Data, get different picklist value in salsforce?

Tags: salesforce

I have requirement like based on **Work Order Service Type**, **Activity** picklist value different like:

if Repair : then picklist value should be Repair and Other.
If Other : then picklist value should be all.

[image]

Please suggest how I can achieve this, do I need to customization or with config we can do this. Tried multiple ways didn't work for me.

Comment: Please check dependent pick lists https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=fields_about_dependent_fields.htm&type=5